# Using LMM for longitudinal data within groups (using statsmodels)

Tags: mixed-model, anova, python, interaction, statsmodels

I am trying to fit a mixed model for repeated measures. My experiment has subjects divided into two groups, with the dependent variable (DV) measured twice for each subject, like so:

| subjectID | time | group | DV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | pre | subject | 24 |
| 101 | post | subject | 85 |
| 102 | pre | control | 32 |
| 102 | post | control | 24 |
| etc | ... | ... | ... |

I want to examine:

1. changes in `DV` over `time`
2. the variability between `groups` at the initial measurement and
3. the variability in changes in `DV` over `time` between `groups` (i.e. interaction between `time` and `group`

I started out with mixed anova but would like to use LMM duu to both having missing data, and wanting to later add other covariates to the model.

I'm using python statsmodels, with the formula api. I feel like I got the formula correct, and assume that 'groups' should be `subjectID`, but I can't seem grasp what the random intercept formula should be. As it is now, the results are very similar to the mixed ANOVA results for group effect and interaction effect, but the time effect is different.

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
model = smf.mixedlm(fr"DV ~ C(group, Treatment('subject')) + C(time, Treatment('pre')) + C(group) * C(time) ", 
                         df, groups= all_data["subjectID"], 
                         re_formula = '~C(time) +1',
                         missing="drop")
```

Am I using the model correctly? specifically - should the groups be `sibjectID` or `groups`, and what should the random intercept formula be?

thanks in advance for any advice or help!